# Is my Theano program actually using the GPU?

Tags: performance, profiling, gpu, gpgpu, theano

Theano claims it's using the GPU; it says what device when it starts up, etc.  Furthermore nvidia-smi says it's being used.

But the running time seems to be exactly the same regardless of whether or not I use it.

Could it have something to do with integer arithmetic?

```
import sys

import numpy as np
import theano
import theano.tensor as T


def ariths(v, ub):
  """Given a sorted vector v and scalar ub, returns multiples of elements in v.

  Specifically, returns a vector containing all numbers j * k < ub where j is in
  v and k >= j.  Some elements may occur more than once in the output.
  """

  lp = v[0]
  v = T.shape_padright(v)
  a = T.shape_padleft(T.arange(0, (ub + lp - 1) // lp - lp, 1, 'int64'))
  res = v * (a + v)
  return res[(res < ub).nonzero()]


def filter_composites(pv, using_primes):
  a = ariths(using_primes, pv.size)
  return T.set_subtensor(pv[a], 0)


def _iterfn(prev_bnds, pv):
  bstart = prev_bnds[0]
  bend = prev_bnds[1]
  use_primes = pv[bstart:bend].nonzero()[0] + bstart
  pv = filter_composites(pv, use_primes)
  return pv


def primes_to(n):
  if n <= 2:
    return np.asarray([])
  elif n <= 3:
    return np.asarray([2])

  res = T.ones(n, 'int8')
  res = T.set_subtensor(res[:2], 0)

  ubs = [[2, 4]]
  ub = 4
  while ub ** 2 < n:
    prevub = ub
    ub *= 2
    ubs.append([prevub, ub])
  (r, u5) = theano.scan(fn=_iterfn,
                        outputs_info=res, sequences=[np.asarray(ubs)])
  return r[-1].nonzero()[0]


def main(n):
  print(primes_to(n).size.eval())

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main(int(sys.argv[1]))
```

Comment: I removed my answer due to it not being very useful. It seems you have implemented an algorithm that just doesn't benefit from the architecture you are using.

Answer (score 3):

The answer is yes. And no. If you profile your code in a GPU enabled Theano installation using [nvprof](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/profiler-users-guide/#abstract), you will see something like this:

```
==16540== Profiling application: python ./theano_test.py
==16540== Profiling result:
Time(%)      Time     Calls       Avg       Min       Max  Name
 49.22%  12.096us         1  12.096us  12.096us  12.096us  kernel_reduce_ccontig_node_c8d7bd33dfef61705c2854dd1f0cb7ce_0(unsigned int, float const *, float*)
 30.60%  7.5200us         3  2.5060us     832ns  5.7600us  [CUDA memcpy HtoD]
 13.93%  3.4240us         1  3.4240us  3.4240us  3.4240us  [CUDA memset]
  6.25%  1.5350us         1  1.5350us  1.5350us  1.5350us  [CUDA memcpy DtoH]
```

i.e. There is a least a reduce operation being performed on your GPU. However, if you modify your main like this:

```
def main():
  n = 100000000 
  print(primes_to(n).size.eval())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import cProfile, pstats
    cProfile.run("main()", "{}.profile".format(__file__))
    s = pstats.Stats("{}.profile".format(__file__))
    s.strip_dirs()
    s.sort_stats("time").print_stats(10)
```

and use [cProfile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/profile.html#module-cProfile) to profile your code, you will see something like this:

```
Thu Mar 10 14:35:24 2016    ./theano_test.py.profile

         486743 function calls (480590 primitive calls) in 17.444 seconds

   Ordered by: internal time
   List reduced from 1138 to 10 due to restriction <10>

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    6.376    6.376   16.655   16.655 {theano.scan_module.scan_perform.perform}
       13    6.168    0.474    6.168    0.474 subtensor.py:2084(perform)
       27    2.910    0.108    2.910    0.108 {method 'nonzero' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       30    0.852    0.028    0.852    0.028 {numpy.core.multiarray.concatenate}
       27    0.711    0.026    0.711    0.026 {method 'astype' of 'numpy.ndarray' objects}
       13    0.072    0.006    0.072    0.006 {numpy.core.multiarray.arange}
        1    0.034    0.034   17.142   17.142 function_module.py:482(__call__)
      387    0.020    0.000    0.052    0.000 graph.py:486(stack_search)
       77    0.016    0.000   10.731    0.139 op.py:767(rval)
      316    0.013    0.000    0.066    0.000 graph.py:715(general_toposort)
```

The slowest operation (just) is the scan call, and looking at the source for scan, you can see that presently, [GPU execution of scan is disabled](https://github.com/Theano/Theano/blob/b7e68d2241d28db48a1a8dadf949ba1a0d97c1c6/theano/scan_module/scan.py#L1012).

So then answer is, yes, the GPU is being used for something in your code, but no, the most time consuming operation(s) are being run on the CPU because GPU execution appears to be hard disabled in the code at present.